# handling repeating-time consuming codes by calling controllers from view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

im very new to mvc and frameworks and i've faced a lot of challenges by now the one that really bugs me is about calling controllers from view or any other ways to handle the code that is going to repeat in every page

say i have a site and the user can be logged or not logged when he/she visits my site 
now if user is logged i want to say "welcome username" in my header view

header view is going to be called from many different controllers 
i guess the right approach is to check if user is logged in each controller and pass that data to the header view

but easier way to do this is to do this directly in the view and get ride of the controllers authentication part

i want to do something like this in the header view :

```
$this->load->controller('user');
$user = $this->user->is_logged();
if($user)
echo "welcome $user";
```

is there a way to do this ? if the answer is yes , is it correct/valid practice ?
and if no , is there any way to reduce the time and coding is this kind of situations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont call controllers from a view!

If you have 'repetitive' tasks - they should be put into a library, or helper, and run from there.

In that library - you have a function like

```
function display_log_status()
{
     if ($this->user->is_logged())
     {
         return "welcome!";
     }
     else
     {
          return "please log in!";
     }
}
```

Then just call "display_log_status()" in your view.

[MVC Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html)

[Creating Libraries in CI](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)